# Importing a large amount of data into MySQL table - escaping special characters

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on getting a large list of entries into a MySQL table. This is coming from a .doc file. I've been able to use Sublime Text find/replace/etc. in order to break them all down into MySQL insert statements, and so far that's worked. My only problem is the special characters aren't escaped and show up as `<?>`'s on the page that displays the entries from the database.

Is there an easy way to ensure all of the data entered gets escped before inserting? I'd hate to have to go through all of them by hand.

Example:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`product-type`, `name`, `description`, `account-type`, `approved`)
VALUES ('Ex', 'Dolar','Company® cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat nonproident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.', '0', '1');
```

When something like the copyright logo for the company is displayed on the page, it shows up as a black triangle with a question mark.

Comment: Can you show us your generated insert statement containing special chars ?

Comment: Edited w/ insert statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed to :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
```

And seems ok (for copyright character at least)

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out. Although all my pages had `<meta charset="utf-8">`, I needed to add `charset=utf8` to my database settings:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8",$dbuser,$dbpass);
```

After that everything was displayed on the page properly. It wasn't actually anything to do w/ special characters, rather character encoding.